# why are my if and else if statements not running?

Tags: if-statement

same as title.

```
  const inputs =document.querySelectorAll('input');
  inputs.forEach(function(_inputs){
    _inputs.readOnly = !_inputs.readOnly;

    if(_inputs.readyOnly == false){
      _inputs.classList.remove("readOnlyItem")
      _inputs.classList.add("notReadOnly")
    }else if(_inputs.readyOnly == true){
      _inputs.classList.add("readOnlyItem")
      _inputs.classList.remove("notReadOnly")
    }
  });
```

As far as I can tell every thing seems right and should be working but the if statments never return true for some reason.

Comment: When I have issues like this, it helps me to console out the thing I'm checking the value of - try running `console.log(_inputs.readOnly)` after `_inputs.readOnly = !_inputs.readOnly;` and see if that helps you diagnose the issue

Comment: Also you're checking `_inputs.readyOnly` in your if statements instead of `_inputs.readOnly`